# Matplotlib Sankey labels and values

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, sankey-diagram

I'm working on a Sankey diagram and I'm experiencing some issues with the labeling process. Is there a way to put the labels and the values of each flow on the same line? I would like them to look like this: "Label: value".

Here are the code and the resulting diagram.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.sankey import Sankey

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8.3, 11.7))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
plt.axis('off')

# these will be provided soon
# Input = ...
# L0 = ...
# L1, L2, L3, L4, L5, L6, L7, L8, L9 = ...
# F9 = ...

sankey = Sankey(ax=ax,
                scale=1 / Input,
                offset=0.6,
                head_angle=135,
                shoulder=0,
                gap=0.2,
                radius=0.1,
                format='%.1f',
                unit='%')
s0 = sankey.add(flows=[Input, -L0, -(Input - L0)],
                labels=['Input 1', 'Loss 0', ''],
                orientations=[0, 1, 0],
                trunklength=1,
                rotation=-90,
                fc='crimson', alpha=0.8)
s1 = sankey.add(flows=[Input - L0, -L1, -L2, -L3, -L4, -L5, -L6, -L7, -L8, -L9, -F9],
                labels=['Input 2', 'Loss 1', 'Loss 2', 'Loss 3', 'Loss 4', 'Loss 5', 'Loss 6', 'Loss 7', 'Loss 8',
                        'Loss 9', 'Output'],
                orientations=[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
                trunklength=1,
                rotation=-90,
                prior=0, connect=(2, 0),
                fc='crimson', alpha=0.6)
diagrams = sankey.finish()
for d in diagrams:
    for t in d.texts:
        t.set_fontsize(10)
        t.set_horizontalalignment('center')
        t.set_verticalalignment('center')

diagrams[0].texts[0].set_position(xy=[0, 0.4])
diagrams[0].texts[2].set_position(xy=[10, 10])

plt.show()
```

Sankey diagram

[image: the resulting output]

Comment: Please add the import of the exact libraries you're using and provide some meaningful values for `Input, colors_2, F9, L0, L1, ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing your input values are the shown percentages, your goal could be reached by manually adding that information to each label. Use `'\n'` when you need a new line, use a dash `' – '` or a colon when writing the percentages on one line. You'll need to reset the `format` and `unit` parameter of the sankey to prevent that the percentage will be added a second time.

As the sankey still is writing the empty format and unit, the text can be updated to remove the empty line and get correct vertical centering.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.sankey import Sankey
from random import randint

Input = 240.1
L0 = 140.1
F9 = 21.1
L = [randint(1,300) for _ in range(9)]
norm_factor = (Input - L0 - F9) / sum(L)

flows_s2 = [Input - L0] + [-l * norm_factor for l in L] + [-F9]
labels_s2 = ['Input 2', 'Loss 1', 'Loss 2', 'Loss 3', 'Loss 4', 'Loss 5', 'Loss 6', 'Loss 7', 'Loss 8', 'Loss 9',
             'Output']
labels_s2_long = [f'{label}\n{flow} %' for label, flow in zip(labels_s2[:1], flows_s2)]
labels_s2_long += [f'{label} – {-flow:.1f} %' for label, flow in zip(labels_s2[1:], flows_s2[1:])]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8.3, 11.7))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
plt.axis('off')
sankey = Sankey(ax=ax,
                scale=2 / Input,
                offset=0.6,
                head_angle=135,
                shoulder=0,
                gap=0.2,
                radius=0.1,
                format='%.1f',
                unit='%')
s0 = sankey.add(flows=[Input, -L0, -(Input - L0)],
                labels=['Input 1', 'Loss 0', ''],
                orientations=[0, 1, 0],
                trunklength=1,
                rotation=-90,
                fc='crimson', alpha=0.8)
sankey.format = ''
sankey.unit = ''
s1 = sankey.add(flows=flows_s2,
                labels=labels_s2_long,
                orientations=[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
                trunklength=1,
                rotation=-90,
                prior=0, connect=(2, 0),
                fc='tomato', alpha=0.6)
diagrams = sankey.finish()
for d in diagrams:
    for t in d.texts:
        text = t.get_text()
        if text[-1] == '\n': # remove empty line at the end, needed for centering
            t.set_text(text[:-1])
        t.set_fontsize(10)
        t.set_verticalalignment('center')
        if text[:4] == 'Loss' and text[:6] != 'Loss 0': # align all loss labels except loss 0
            t.set_horizontalalignment('left')
            xy = t.get_position()
            t.set_position(xy=(0.18, xy[1]))
        else:
            t.set_horizontalalignment('center')
        #t.set_bbox(dict(facecolor='red', alpha=0.5, edgecolor='blue'))

diagrams[0].texts[0].set_position(xy=(0, 0.42)) # adjust position of input 1
diagrams[0].texts[1].set_position(xy=(1.75, diagrams[0].texts[1].get_position()[1])) # adjust pos. of loss 0
diagrams[0].texts[2].set_text('')  # remove output 1 as it coincides with input 2
diagrams[1].texts[-1].set_position(xy=(diagrams[1].texts[-1].get_position()[0], -5)) # adjust pos. of output


plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: output]

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot! it was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I just added some code to correct the vertical centering of the 'loss' lines.

Comment: hi @JohanC , 
I just figured out,  if you set unit=None, sankey will not plot any value. 
Like this the label get vertically nicer places automatically. Unfortunately, horizontally it is still 'center'.

Comment: Thanks for this.  This is the best doco for my use-case that I've found anywhere and I now have a working conceptual model. Cheers!